# Why is 'name' a defined variable by default in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope, namespaces, undefined, scoping

I just ran into this by chance when demonstrating variable scoping in [this repl](https://repl.it/@foozie/TenderRuddyHashfunction). Take this code for example:

```
var myFunc = function() {
    var name = 'Matt';
    var functionScopedVariable = "I'm in the function"
    console.log(name); // => 'Matt'
    console.log(functionScopedVariable); // => "I'm in the function"
}

myFunc();
console.log(name) // => ''
console.log(typeof name) // => string
console.log(functionScopedVariable) // => ReferenceError: functionScopedVariable is not defined
```

I thought this might be some weird namespacing with repl, however go to **any** website, open up your console, and type `name` and it'll output `""` instead of `ReferenceError: name is not defined`. What is going on here? It's not breaking anything, just super curious. I've googled around a bit but I can't seem to find anything on this topic.

Comment: because the global object, `window` has a `name` property - this isn't a "javascript" default as such (e.g. nodejs does not have a global `name` property), this is to do with HTML/DOM - for instance, you also have things like `Image` as a global, nothing to do with the javascript *language* though

Comment: And that's specific to browsers, not Javascript. Got it.